# Why does AES cipher suite get higher priority than ECDH in TLS cipher negotiation?

Tags: ssl, https, cryptography, tls1.2, pki

I observe network traffic (using Wireshark) when I make any HTTPS connection, and noted that in the `CLIENT HELLO` step,
AES cipher negotiation algorithm

```
Cipher Suite: TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x1301)
Cipher Suite: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x1302)
```

gets higher precedence than the ECDH cipher negotiation algorithm

```
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02b)
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc02c)
```

As per my understanding, the session key (shared secret) generated in case of AES will be encrypted by the public key of web server (at web browser side) and pass to web server, which can be compromised by eavesdropper by using public key of web server by sniffing packet and provided his/her own shared secret.

But the session key (shared secret) generated in case of ECDH is generated based on mathematical function and derived same key at both the end(web server and web browser) without actual exchange of key.

If that is the case, ECDH type of cipher suite should have *higher* priority than AES type cipher suite.

Educate me in case I misinterpreted something here.

Note: I noticed, almost every time web server negotiated the ECDH algorithm.

Comment: Your first two suites are TLS1.3 suites; in TLS1.3 the suite does not control keyexchange. TLS1.3 keyexchange NEVER encrypts any secret with the public key of the server, and even if it did that wouldn't be compromised by sniffing because the whole point of public key encryption is to prevent that. In fact TLS1.3 keyexchange ALWAYS uses either FFDHE or ECHDE except for one resumption case. Your last 3 suites use ECDHE keyexchange, but only work in TLS1.2. TLS1.3 is preferred to TLS1.2 because it is better. And this is not programming or development and offtopic.

Comment: if i understood correctly,
Just because TLS-1.3 have higher precedence over TLS-1.2; That why TLS-1.3 cipher suite have higher precedence over TLS-1.2 cipher suite.(without considering key exchange). 
TLS-1.3 with cipher suite FFDHE or ECHDE is ideal scenario.

Comment: The session key and the shared secret are not the same thing. The session key is never transmitted.

Comment: @user207421, Can you elaborate here or have any reference document where i can clear my understanding about difference between session key and shared secret.

Comment: So reading the comments this is simply a naming misunderstanding. The TLS 1.3 ciphers don't include the key agreement algorithm in their name which lead to the misunderstanding that they are less secure than the ciphers that have a key agreement alg name included.